# Checkbox with condition in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I convert

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fea" <?php if($this->session->userdata("fea") == 1) echo "checked='true'"; ?> />
```

to the codeigniter form.

Please help THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$checked = FALSE;
if($this->session->userdata("fea") == 1) { $checked = TRUE; }
$data = array(
    'name'        => 'fea',
    'id'          => 'fea',
    'value'       => your_checkbox_value_here,
    'checked'     => $checked
    );

echo form_checkbox($data);
```

Comment: See this reference: codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: that is okay, but it is not getting checked once session is set? but when i write in basic htm format it works? PLeas Help

Comment: yea thats just a variable name but be sure you use $data1 as parameter to form_checkbox as well, like form_checkbox($data1);

Comment: The problem is we have to provide value also inside array. so provide +1 for the question